# <Link to> does not work

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a parent-child coupling component, based on react tutorial, I wrote the following code. However, it gave this error message:`TypeError: this.context.router.createHref is not a function`.
Any ideas?
Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(<Router>
                <App />
                </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Component/Header';
import Button1 from './Component/Button1';
import Home from './Component/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
      const Main = () => (
                          <div>
                          <Router>
                            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                            <Route path="/button1" component={Button1} />
                           </Router>
                          </div>
                           );

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
         <ul>
          <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/button1">Button1</Link></li>
         </ul>
        <Main />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429185/cannot-read-property-history-of-undefined-react-router-v4-create-react-ap/45430091#45430091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade react-router-dom to V4.1.2, it works!

Comment: I am having real trouble to resolve this error messes. 
I am using `react-router-dom` 4.3.1. My LinkContainer is inside a shared component,  and my router object contains only (in JSON): `{"pathname":"/news","route":"/news","query":{},"asPath":"/news"}`.
I feel like my context doesn't have the expected type for router. What should I do to make this router compatible?

Answer (score 1):

All `react-router` and `react-router-dom` components will need to be a child of your `<Router />`.

Try making the following changes;

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const Main = () => (
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/button1" component={Button1} />
      </div>
    );

    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
           <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/button1">Button1</Link></li>
           </ul>
          <Main />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

You may also want to add `exact` to `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />` if you don't want both components rendered at the same time.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it still displays the same error message.

Comment: Would you post your updated code please. It should work. Here a [basic example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) from the documentation if you need.

Comment: I have posted my code to the another answer. I wrote my code based on that example, it's weird that I keep getting this error message.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this issue report](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/rapscallion/issues/8), if you do `npm install react-router-dom@next`, your example should work. By default, it installs `v0.0.0`.

Comment: I have already done that, the current version is 4.0.0-beta.3